# Angular 2 Routing management between two apps

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have build with two angular 2 apps:

```
 -index.html (first app) 
 -guest (folder with second app)
 |- index.html (second app)
```

In my case I need to bootstrap second app when specific route opened ('/guest'). So as I run it by webpack-dev-server, if I open url `/guest` in browser, second app is launched (because it opens index.html from guest folder, since I have no router handling for `/guest` route). But is there way, to bootstrap second app for any route?

Comment: have you checked lazy loading for angular module.

Comment: @sri ram, actually - no, but I don,t understand how it can helps in my case.

Comment: can you elaborate me, what is it that you're trying to achieve and why do you need 2 angular app and why cant you use angular modules and lazy load based on the /guest route instead of creating 2 angular app

Comment: @sri ram, first app contains all logic and a lot of dependencies (so it's generate big vendor.js file because used many node modules), second app - has minimum dependencies and size, it simple view for guests, so second app needed to productive first bootstrap for guest users (winning in difference in vendor.js file sizes).

Comment: based on the user choice he/she will signup or use guest right?

Comment: @sri ram, no, it's only separate view

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139152/discussion-between-sri-ram-and-qwe-asd).